# Docusign demo Connect Listener - Unable to get callback on secure https link

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am working with docusign demo account and successfully getting callbacks on http (port 80) from connect listener. I have now purchased and installed the SSL certificates on server and able to access the callback link from inside and outside the network. When I changes the http:// link on connect service configuration to https://, it gives me the following error:

> https://esign/api/event/envelop-event-occured ::
>   Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
>   channel.

Anybody who can help me with this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you manually go to your endpoint from an external location, do you get certificate errors or does it validate without manual intervention?

Comment: It validates without any manual intervention.

Comment: Without sharing more information here about the endpoint I'm not sure we can help (which I understand with production links). I'd contact DocuSign Customer Support to resolve this issue. Let them know that you posted on SO and you were directed to them, sharing this post may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks from DocuSign must be using https with TLS 1.1 or above.
Please read here for more information about that - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/mutual-tls-intro